# Access the original purchase date of the app from the user's App store account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit

Is there a way to access the original purchase date of your app from the uses's App Store Account? The information is there as you can view it from iTunes. You might think you could use the StoreKit framework but I don't see how. The StoreKit framework seems to be for In-App products not the app itself.

Silas

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. And you will not be able to do something like a "Limited Time Trial" as of  [Section 11.9 App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)